# User-defined column and table names in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a small MVC application, which uses EntityFramework for DAL and I want to provide users an option to manually set "user-friendly" column/table names based on preference. For example, there is an Entity `Transaction`, having a `[Table("TransactionData")]` attribute. The table name is used in reports, i.e. on the view with transactions report, the name of view will be `TransactionData`. But, I want to provide users an option to provide custom names, i.e. for some user it will be `Payments Data`, for some `Bills`, etc. Same applies to the columns.

However, I am not sure, what is the best practice to do this with EF/EF Core CodeFirst design. It is clear that with sql queries I could go back and forth, having custom mapping via some configurations table, but what about EF?

Comment: just use the ui to change user experience with individual preferences

Comment: Am i understanding this correctly and you want to use aliasses for table names and columns? Or are we talking about different instances of the database where the same table and column structure is used but those tables and columns are named differently according to the end users need?

Comment: @Thomas, I want to use aliases, but these aliases are user specific, i.e. each user has his/her own aliases defined for the tables.

Comment: Then I would not put that in the database but in some sort of mapping-layer in which you lay the relation between the user-table-name and the sql-table-name. Or if it's not user specific but instance/company specific you could have a look at the OnModelCreating found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/